# Nvigation Windows Phone Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to navigate from one page to an another for my windows phone app, but the problem is that if I use this type of code:

```
private void hyperlinkButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
}
```

The debugger says that **NavigationService is not available in the context**

What should I do?

Comment: Are you use Windows Phone 8(Silver LIght Application) ?

Answer (score 0):

NavigationService does not exist because it is only used in Windows Phone Silverlight apps.

Use Frame.Navigate():

```
Frame.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your use project template **Windows Phone 8.0**  OR  **Windows phone 8.0(Sliverlight)**

then try to below one :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And if your are using **Windows phone 8.1** then :

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

**OR**

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);
```